# Parsing JSON file to use in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, cors, fetch-api, preflight

I am trying to parse a JSON file so I can access its data using JavaScript. Here is a sample of the JSON file:

```
 "Veg": {
"French beans 300g": 81969,
"Bunched beetroot": 78272,
"Squash box": 45450,
"Bunched carrots 500g": 90435,
"Courgettes x3": 17824,
"Fennel x1": 14816,
"Shiitake mushrooms 150g": 5166,
"Spring onions 125g": 65034,
"Red peppers x2": 11671,
```

An here is the JavaScript I am using:

```
<script>
    var sourceData;

        // Initial data load
        fetch("data.json", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            })
        }).then(function (body) {
            return body.json();
        }).then(function (data) {
            sourceData = data;
        });
</script>
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful
```

and

```
Fetch API cannot load <file path> Preflight response is not successful
```

Comment: how are you sending the request? What I mean is, are you using cURL or Postman or a browser? If you are using a browser, what does the address bar say in the browser? Does it start with `file:///` or `http://`?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: browser, file:///

Comment: You cannot use XHR requests (fetch) from a browser window opened from the file browser. Your HTML file must be opened from a sever for this to work.

Comment: I understand. Thanks, i'll give this a try

Comment: Is there a way I can work on this offline using the file:/// method ?

Comment: Nope....do you have python...are you on a Mac?

Comment: Yes and yes @RandyCasburn

Comment: it's easy then. Open a shell, navigate to the folder with your HTML file and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` - then in your browser you can go `http://localhost:8080' and your file will work as expected. (assuming it is named index.html)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks so much

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
parseVariable = JSON.parse(JsonVariable);

console.log(parseVariable);
```